# Что это за строчка? chrome-extension://napifgkjbjeodgmfjmgncljmnmdefpbf /styles.css

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, chrome-extension, pagespeed-insights

Нужно оптимизировать сайт, но в инспекторе показывает, что это расширение не используется на 100%, а вес имеет. "chrome-extension://napifgkjbjeodgmfjmgncljmnmdefpbf /styles.css" - что это такое? нужно ли удалить?
[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это [какое-то расширение](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/coupons-at-checkout/napifgkjbjeodgmfjmgncljmnmdefpbf) внедряет свои стили на сайт

Заходишь по: `chrome://extensions/`, ищешь `napifgkjbjeodgmfjmgncljmnmdefpbf`

Расширение - `Автоматическое применение купонов` (какает)

Можешь его удалить, либо:

[image: выключить тута]

пс, я выключаю расширения, которые созданы для нескольких действий, когда ими не пользуюсь, например впн или скачиватели какие-нибудь..